# pattern matching - implementation of ?, ?c, ?v

Tags: scheme, sicp

I'm trying to understand the pattern matching in sicp.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amf5lTZ0UTc&list=PL8FE88AA54363BC46&index=7

He created these 3 procedures in the pattern rules but there's no implementation.

Is there an implmentation for these?

pattern matching - implementation of ?, ?c, ?v

https://github.com/f03lipe/sicp-code/blob/master/code/4A.scm

```
foo     - matches exactly foo
(f a b) - matches list in which first element if f, second is a, third is b
(? x)       - matches anything, call it x
(?c x)  - matches constant, call it x
(?v x)  - matches variable, call it x

(define deriv-rules
    '(
        ( (dd (?c c) (? v))         0)
        ( (dd (?v v) (? v))         1)
        ( (dd (?v u) (? v))         0)
```

Or is there no implementation at all since these are just the rules that are being evaluated?

Comment: How can I understand what it means to match  just foo and (f a b)?

Comment: When the professor says foo matches foo - does he mean something like   *  or +   means exactly what it is?

Answer (score 1):

They are in fact not procedures. They are part of the syntax, representing an arbitrary constant, and arbitrary variable, or anything. So in the match procedure. You can see in minute 35 of the video, this:

```
((ARBITRARY-CONSTANT? pat)
 (if (CONSTANT? exp)
     (extend-dict pat exp dict)
     'failed))
((ARBITRARY-VARIABLE? pat)
 (if (VARIBLE? exp)
     (extend-dict pat exp dict)
     'failed))
((ARBITRARY-EXPRESSION? pat)
 (extend-dict pat exp dict))
```

This is where this syntax is going to be evaluated. Based on this, We can simply define the procedures as:

```
(define (tagged-list? tag exp)
  (eq? tag (car exp)))

(define (arbitrary-constant? pat)    ; (?c c)
  (tagged-list? '?c pat))
(define (arbitrary-variable? pat)    ; (?v v)
  (tagged-list? '?v pat))
(define (arbitrary-expression? pat)  ; (? v)
  (tagged-list? '? pat))
```

Ant that is basically it. These are used to abstract the pattern, so you can change the syntax later, without having to change the match procedure.

Comment: The way it's explained in the video seems just too abstract for me.  Is there an easier way to understand how to learn this pattern matching?

Comment: @runners3431 do you mean pattern matching in general, or this specific example? What don't you understand?

Comment: rptx: i failed to understand that deriv-rules is just a list using symbolic quotation. So i can take the car or the cadr of any the rules to parse it.